# Why is my jQuery not adding display on second div I create?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I try adding the first contact and submit it, it shows in the div **id=contact**.

The function hide/show is working then.

But as soon as I add a second contact it's not working anymore.

Seems, jQuery doesn't enter display...

```js
function css(){
    $('.contacts').css('background-color', 'lightblue');
}

function visibility() {
    $("#vis").click(function(){
        $(".description").toggle();
        return false;
    });
};

$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("form").submit(function (event) {
        var fname = $('#fname').val();
        var lname = $('#lname').val();
        var desc = $('#desc').val();
        $('.contacts').append( "<div id='contact'>"+fname+"<br>"+lname+"<br><button id='vis'>Show/Hide</button><div class='description' style='display:;'>"+desc+"</div></div>");
        // alert(fname);
        event.preventDefault();
        css();
        visibility();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal information:</legend>
        First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Description:</legend>
        <textarea id="desc" value="desc"> </textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>

<div class="contacts"> </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can't have more than one element with the same ID in html. Consider using "data-id" for that purpose or class and find closest parent->child of button.

Comment: @Ivar No, he doesn't. He calls visibility() function after appending html.

Comment: Good call. The initial indentation got me confused.

Comment: It's due to the `style='display:;'`. If you remove it, or change it to `display: none;` it works fine. (At least as long as you don't submit it twice. Then the multiple id's issue kicks in.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in comment - You can't have multiple elements with the same ID in html. You also don't have to add listeners for each button. You can add listener for body and selector as second parameter (see attached code).

```js
function css(){
    $('.contacts').css('background-color', 'lightblue');
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
  //this way you don't need to add listener for each button
  $('body').on('click', '.vis', function() {
    $(this).closest('.contact').find('.description').toggle();
  });
  
  $("form").submit(function (event) {
    var fname = $('#fname').val();
    var lname = $('#lname').val();
    var desc = $('#desc').val();
    $('.contacts').append( "<div class='contact'>"+fname+"<br>"+lname+"<br><button class='vis'>Show/Hide</button><div class='description'>"+desc+"</div></div>");
    event.preventDefault();
    css();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal information:</legend>
        First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Description:</legend>
        <textarea id="desc" value="desc"> </textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>

<div class="contacts"> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much @ElChupacabra, make sense now!